# linear functional f and it's formula

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear functional such that

$$ f=5\epsilon^*_1-3\epsilon_2^*+\epsilon_3^* $$

where $\epsilon^*_1, \epsilon_2^*,\epsilon^*_3$ is dual to $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ find formula for f.

I have problem with finding dual basis here, how to approach it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition

$$\epsilon^*_i(\epsilon_j)=\delta_{ij}\implies \begin{cases}e^*_1\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=x\\{}\\e^*_2\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=y\\{}\\e^*_3\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=z\end{cases}$$

End the solution now.

Comment: so it's just $f=5x-3y+z$ ?

Comment: @Mario As ridiculously simple as that...and don't let the downvote confuse you.

Comment: ok ,thanks a lot